# How to find strictly positive solutions of a nonlinear system of equations in R?

Tags: r, equation-solving, nonlinear-equation

I have a system of equations with L+2 variables that looks something like:

zL = f(z0, ..., z(L-1)), z0 = g(zL), zl = h_l(z(l-1)) for 0<l<L, and m(c)= 0.

Here the functions f,g,h_l (0<l<L) and m are nonlinear, and I already have a method **fun_eq(z0,z1,...,zL,c)** that returns:

```
c(z0-g, z1-h_1,z2-h_2 ..., z(L-1)- h_(L-1), zL-f, m(c))
```

and I would like to determine the value of **c(z0,z1,...,zL,c)** with all the variables being strictly positive. I tried using:

```
library(nleqslv)
nleqslv(some_initial_conditions, fun_eq)
```

but some of the solutions turned out to be negative. Is there a way to restrict my solution space to only positive c(z0,z1,...,zL,c)? or are there other methods to solve nonlinear systems of equations with positivity constraints?

Comment: You could perform a change of variables so that the parameters of the system are `log(zi)` instead of `zi`.

Comment: try functions in the `alabama` package ("constrained nonlinear optimization") ?